# numpy array: accessing element in a loop gives an error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

This code throws an exception:

```
"list index out of range"
```

at the line marked below.

```
col_sig_squared = [np.zeros(shape=(1,6), dtype=int)]

def calculate_col_sigma_square(matrix):
    mx = np.asarray(matrix)
    for(x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(matrix):
    if(x > 4):
            continue
    else:
        val = matrix[x][y] - x_bar_col[x]
        val = val**2
        EXCEPTION-->print col_sig_squared[y]
```

Why is this a problem? `col_sig_squared` is an array with indices. Why can't I access it like this. Tried a bunch of things but not sure why this syntax is wrong. I'm new to Python and its intricacies, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Generally don't use `matrix[x][y]` use `matrix[x,y]` there is a big difference if `x` is not a scalar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more common to express NumPy *array* vectors using `shape = (N,)`. For instance:

```
>>> col_sig_1byN = np.zeros(shape=(1,6), dtype=int)
>>> col_sig_N = np.zeros(shape=(6,), dtype=int)
>>> print col_sig_1byN
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]]
>>> print col_sig_N
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

You can index `col_sig_N` as `col_sig_N[p]`, but for `col_sig_1byN` you have to do `col_sig_1byN[0,p]` - note that `[x,y]` is the way to index into a multidimensional NumPy array.

To index a whole row/column you can do `[x,:]`/`[:,y]`.

And, [as kindall said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13056195/120261), you should not embed your array in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the message tells you what is wrong pretty clearly. `y` is bigger at that point than the number of items in `col_sig_squared`. This doesn't surprise me because `col_sig_squared` is defined as a list with one item, a NumPy array:

```
col_sig_squared = [np.zeros(shape=(1,6), dtype=int)]
```

This means that only `col_sig_squared[0]` is valid.

Maybe you meant:

```
col_sig_squared = np.zeros(shape=(1,6), dtype=int)
```

Now `col_sig_squared` is a NumPy array.